# Shorten if statement check for matching argument

Tags: bash, shell-script, test

I have this bit of code which does what it's supposed to do:

```
first_arg="$1";
if [ "$first_arg" != "patch" -a "$first_arg" != "major" -a "$first_arg" != "minor" -a "$first_arg" != "prerelease" ]; then
  echo "First argument needs to match a valid npm version argument (patch, minor, major, etc).";
  exit 1;
fi
```

it's checking ensure that the first argument is one of (patch, major, minor, prerelease).

However, is there a shorter / less-verbose way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `case`, which works in any standard shell:

```
case "$1" in
    patch|major|minor|prerelease) ;;
    *) echo "First argument needs to match a valid npm version argument (patch, minor, major, etc)." >&2; exit 1;;
esac
```

An alternative in Bash/ksh/zsh is to use a regular expression match:

```
if ! [[ $1 =~ ^(patch|major|minor|prerelease)$ ]]; then
    echo "First argument needs to match a valid npm version argument (patch, minor, major, etc)." >&2;
    exit 1;
fi
```

Comment: that is the most bizarre syntax ever lol

Comment: @StephenKitt: Just a side note: You don't need to quote $1 inside the `[[ .... ]]` construct in bash/zsh/ksh.

Comment: @StephenKitt : I can't sensibly edit it, because SE requires that at least 6 characters are changed, if I edit a post. In any case, the issue is not really important, and in particular does not affect the validity of the answer, so we can leave it with this. After all, it's in the comments too.

Comment: I assume using quotes like `"$1" =~ ^regex$` won't hurt though.

Comment: @AlexanderMills : No. If you enjoy them, use them ;-)  Actually, some people always use quotes, because they don't want to think all the time whether we do have to quote or whether the quotes are optional.